# What is this thing on the engine of a Cessna 500 Citation I?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, private-jets

I've noticed something on the engine of this bizjet. Could somebody explain what that is? 
[image: cessna 500]

[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Policia-Federal-Argentina/Cessna-500-Citation/2768904/L/&sid=54501445151b2d974b17b6267cc58d0b) (image modified to indicate location of fairing).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are the fairings containing the mechanisms for the engine's reverse thrust system. See [this photo](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zgt6trCTf2s/VkeDthBlAuI/AAAAAAAAIbs/t-FTKSAWro0/s1600/DSC_0999.JPG) (copyrighted) of the similar reverse thrust "buckets" deployed on a Citation 550.

See this example of a similar thrust reverser system deployed on a different aircraft type:

[image]

*<sub>Image [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Klm_f100_ph-kle_arp.jpg), public domain</sub>*

See also Wikipedia's article on [Thrust Reversal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_reversal).

Comment: A common name for this is a "stang"

Comment: @SteveH A "stang fairing", yes, you're right.

Comment: Copyright image nicely handled!